# Authlogic gem: use last_request_at column at session level not in user level

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authlogic

Problem: If I logged in as the same user on two devices(say A and B) and I use my application in one device(A) whereas the other device(B) remains inactive. The device B does not logout when the session expires while using feature *logout_on_timeout*.

I am trying to implement *logout_on_timeout* feature of authlogic gem, which I successfully implemented but the problem is authlogic updates the *last_request_at* attribute of User in every request no matter the browser or devices where it logged in. So if I logged in the same user from mobile as well as from desktop and one of the device is active then the other device remains active too because it uses the same shared *last_request_at* attribute from User.

Reference code from authlogic gem: lib/authlogic/acts_as_authentic/logged_in_status.rb

```rb
        # Returns true if the last_request_at > logged_in_timeout.
          def logged_in?
            unless respond_to?(:last_request_at)
              raise(
                "Can not determine the records login state because " \
                  "there is no last_request_at column"
              )
            end
            !last_request_at.nil? && last_request_at > logged_in_timeout.seconds.ago
          end
```

So How can I solve this problem? Is there any way to implement it at the session-level? Like using *last_request_at* in UserSession model.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to not use the *logout_on_timeout* feature but rather use the *remember_me* feature then override the *remember_me_for* method in UserSession and set the dynamic value. Because *logout_on_timeout* uses *last_request_at* attribute value from the *User* to check if session timeout or not, and last_request_at is shared in all session, so When a user opens an app in two devices then both will remain active if one of them is active(kinda incomplete feature or bug maybe).

Also, update the session(ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session) for the current user and change the session's data column value with the generated value from instance method *generate_cookie_for_saving* of UserSession at the end of each request because authlogic only update the session only when creating or deleting the UserSession.

**Note: I am using *activerecord-session_store* gem to persist session in the database.**